# R Assigning x or y coordinate to cells of a raster to perform calculations

Tags: r, spatial, raster

Is there any solution to assign to assign X or Y coordinate to all of the cells of a raster image using R?

For example, suppose I have a raster with 3x3 cells. The lower left coordinate is X=7,Y=15 (in meters), and resolution is +10 m for both, X and Y direction (X increases rightward, and Y upward). Then, I would like to generate raster surfaces where each cell has the X and Y value, like these ones:

```
X raster
7  17  27
7  17  27
7  17  27

Y surface
35  35  35
25  25  25
15  15  15
```

UPDATE: [this](http://www.geografiafisica.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/subset.tif) is the actual raster object.

Is there any way to do this?

I tried the package 'raster', but couldn't find a solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you `dput(your_raster_object)` for us?

Comment: I'd just create a "sister matrix" with the values you desire, then if necessary convert to a raster object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution that I found, inspired in the comment submitted by @Carl.

Suppose my raster is called `d`, with these characteristics:

```
class       : RasterLayer
dimensions  : 59, 67, 3953  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 90, 90  (x, y)
extent      : 482855.6, 488885.6, 4763517, 4768827  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-3 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
data source : in memory
names       : subset
values      : 328, 1120  (min, max)
```

I first generated a matrix with the x coordinates values:

```
xm<-matrix(xFromCell(d,c(1:3953)),nrow=59,byrow=TRUE)
```

Then created a raster with the matrix:

```
x<-raster(xm,xmn=482855.6, xmx=488885.6,ymn=4763517,ymx=4768827)
```

And finally, assigned its projection:

```
projection(x)<-"+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-3 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

I also displayed the raster, to see if results where OK...

```
plot(x)
```

[image: raster image where each cell has the x-coordinate value]

...and read the raster description

```
x
class       : RasterLayer
dimensions  : 59, 67, 3953  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 90, 90  (x, y)
extent      : 482855.6, 488885.6, 4763517, 4768827  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-3 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
data source : in memory
names       : layer
values      : 482900.6, 488840.6  (min, max)
```

I repeated these steps, but using `yFromCell` in the first step.