# Computing weights from latitude to apply to raster stack values

Tags: r, r-raster

I am currently trying to apply weights to the original precipitation values of my Raster Stack object, called "landCO2". These weights are to take into account the differences in area between the equator and poles. However, I am not sure how to approach applying these to the existing values of the Raster Stack. The idea would be to apply the weights to the original values of each of the 138 raster layers, and then eventually plot these values on a global map with wrld_simpl. Here is what was done so far:

```
library(raster)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(rasterVis)


data("wrld_simpl")
b <- wrld_simpl

landCO2 <- mask(RCP1pctCO2Median, b)
CO2new <- rasterToPoints(landCO2)
weightCO2 <- cos(CO2new[,"y"]*(pi/180))
CO2new[,3:ncol(CO2new)] = apply(CO2new[,3:ncol(CO2new)], 2, function(x) x * weightCO2)
avgCO2 <- colSums(CO2new[,3:ncol(CO2new)])/sum(weightCO2)
```

However, this approach obtains an average across all grid cells per layer, effectively creating 138 averages, which is fine. That said, I would like to similarly apply the weights to the values of landCO2 instead, so that the values across the 8192 grid cells for each of the 138 raster layers are appropriately transformed using the approach above. Evidently, this would be done prior to rasterToPoints being applied.

To do what I would like, I tried the following:

```
landCO2<-mask(RCP1pctCO2Median,b)
weightCO2 <- cos(landCO2[,"y"]*(pi/180)) #Notice that I skipped the "rasterToPoints" stage and   replaced CO2new with landCO2 to directly work with landCO2 for this
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Error in landCO2[, "y"] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

landCO2 looks like this:

```
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 64, 128, 8192, 138  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 2.8125, 2.789327  (x, y)
extent      : -181.4062, 178.5938, -89.25846, 89.25846  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       :    layer.1,    layer.2,    layer.3,    layer.4,    layer.5,    layer.6,    layer.7,   
layer.8,    layer.9,   layer.10,   layer.11,   layer.12,   layer.13,   layer.14,   layer.15, ... 
min values  : 0.42964514, 0.43375653, 0.51749371, 0.50838983, 0.45366730, 0.53099146, 0.49757186,
0.45697752, 0.41382199, 0.46082401, 0.45516687, 0.51857087, 0.41005131, 0.45956529, 0.47497867, ... 
max values  :   96.30350,  104.08584,   88.92751,   97.49373,   89.57201,   90.58570,   86.67651,   
88.33519,   96.94720,  101.58247,   96.07792,   93.21948,   99.59785,   94.26218,   90.62138, ...
```

Why would the above error emerge? Is this also the correct approach to apply the weights to landCO2?

Here is from:

```
dput(landCO2)

datanotation = "FLT4S", byteorder = c(value = "little"), 
nodatavalue = -3.4e+38, NAchanged = FALSE, nbands = 138L, 
bandorder = c(value = "BIL"), offset = 0L, toptobottom = TRUE, 
blockrows = 0L, blockcols = 0L, driver = "raster", open = FALSE), 
data = new(".MultipleRasterData", values = structure(logical(0), .Dim = c(0L, 
0L)), offset = 0, gain = 1, inmemory = FALSE, fromdisk = TRUE, 
    nlayers = 138L, dropped = NULL, isfactor = FALSE, attributes = list(), 
    haveminmax = TRUE, min = c(3.51323445746594, 2.92551451275358, 
    3.76379186167912, 3.3067384979661, 3.34126201329632, 
    3.08386133801832, 3.01129632333484, 3.0647601880446, 
    3.48453623055105, 3.03053231936106, 3.19536433344149, 
    3.52855495856725, 2.90104612158757, 3.56892638125178, 
    3.47426237221953, 3.36702133980949, 3.48315423643726, 
    3.92361587221995, 3.90687036742463, 4.01543228703232, 
    3.41304727244007, 3.49068809707965, 3.2989754752411, 
    4.08699701583828, 2.85441317825034, 3.97032106120605, 
    3.684871323053, 3.44885465128755, 3.41068716698003, 3.71867905821301, 
    3.63124173755822, 3.36029075859188, 3.51076291417485, 
    3.60606616807582, 3.85469010434708, 3.62363212746417, 
    4.01465470183506, 3.90460196846042, 3.84035711667821, 
    4.47918876746572, 3.55786634099786, 3.93571036946891, 
    3.46479833997364, 4.15353306379117, 4.6771440494922, 
    3.76401468863884, 3.68025763686699, 3.98433894706614, 
    3.91096955447224, 3.43559741885861, 4.00445031471232, 
    4.48086544565188, 3.87482981677749, 4.08332665795915, 
    4.31136149250093, 3.70382263043114, 3.82149420265705, 
    4.0976117612541, 4.72182125382113, 3.84831596125847, 
    4.20844965732288, 3.79496924067602, 3.82120403737645, 
    3.96484623698029, 4.79580486673734, 4.03934290043253, 
    3.78843141554031, 4.04144783063136, 3.88475518193445, 
    3.77580790845968, 4.22916891094863, 3.37891057351953, 
    3.76609718198318, 3.66466763443896, 4.35687029283038, 
    4.15186590607846, 3.5213297389571, 3.81840347326943, 
    4.40712918335291, 4.49926237706677, 4.18081811171593, 
    4.23534950568547, 4.03825622270233, 4.19584640962629, 
    3.9942848069586, 3.60301350528971, 3.66142267849031, 
    4.41059042526361, 4.02642647615039, 3.96002336497629, 
    4.33060831293324, 4.56909277397865, 4.15728244422731, 
    4.95208776068967, 4.54139118465677, 4.25662558990673, 
    4.61052828421067, 4.15774228504737, 4.49014597435756, 
    4.48774327753287, 5.04747852185112, 4.41152644270915, 
    3.90896636477584, 3.87957397457568, 5.03593959365389, 
    4.27441673938052, 4.75848660621224, 4.3730213657783, 
    4.11031913867645, 5.53989297335251, 4.86124819051654, 
    4.11291051062372, 4.64780621813198, 4.67344226009189, 
    4.97821775717528, 4.87561446464774, 4.235786708869, 5.21463406723742, 
    4.91386599564275, 4.5040326461617, 4.39755890397611, 
    4.1122798656679, 5.62129607988027, 4.06041000097652, 
    5.78230509522252, 4.52243176940702, 4.33450278497182, 
    6.33154314118987, 4.84194052422235, 4.36239409992561, 
    5.06536910154253, 5.36775565871968, 4.58622692133259, 
    3.97402715566745, 4.38483710357093, 5.63010312542135, 
    5.19084796017202, 4.1911775173503), max = c(187.826931949416, 
    156.6457731009, 172.60496802628, 150.653561843192, 163.464290379554, 
    153.660276870287, 184.438549579016, 175.015738903312, 
    162.894831787447, 166.379381638683, 157.147247755231, 
    175.804302409214, 168.281236826442, 162.953071545666, 
    177.617207366887, 176.066608043038, 176.134624167252, 
    183.170432230683, 180.123080536513, 165.758984489366, 
    153.273621544173, 166.31783216726, 191.256207353269, 
    181.834164471366, 174.520181090338, 184.23551817623, 
    171.416536999497, 165.081042726422, 193.315459441979, 
    179.3304157447, 159.511279217247, 172.87064976477, 177.989077667051, 
    171.338298245905, 197.234144158504, 179.725063566265, 
    180.454647608295, 176.538985130977, 167.484739904838, 
    169.59549226423, 178.845183911962, 219.227785511576, 
    179.302375539991, 189.70609536145, 176.671747164801, 
    177.727204008252, 177.685635778916, 171.556028157277, 
    171.660911495565, 182.604148474644, 178.880778257735, 
    175.510428522397, 206.251924111661, 182.791122960718, 
    173.389614745975, 172.956023947333, 195.719172262432, 
    179.013389209727, 177.013185397468, 190.490072804889, 
    173.58294588578, 208.348677327084, 182.333424891621, 
    192.639120889362, 199.178892716937, 206.56841288783, 
    187.576048950698, 209.337462111751, 232.501635693939, 
    236.489306009982, 190.710977550501, 189.469236022643, 
    192.935159127228, 207.684714429639, 180.671009264941, 
    180.381004577515, 169.700639328308, 203.160405447161, 
    205.799407036166, 202.479083081546, 169.195944012218, 
    213.597443973355, 188.696902641166, 181.865464907605, 
    210.356417980395, 186.55099964459, 176.471593682072, 
    167.473492395052, 188.925691105779, 182.676410237466, 
    192.553436647052, 177.382951924105, 187.143067376759, 
    217.646413810112, 201.400167227448, 226.508857402951, 
    176.276089741395, 210.412824002824, 189.672038419686, 
    189.197220375707, 182.771473729409, 198.749990872168, 
    194.103429280842, 165.76628240291, 188.975499918648, 
    185.64837067388, 197.874000910364, 202.24484545222, 198.701451325542, 
    196.977756579872, 220.808595710649, 194.134417466921, 
    190.265171994542, 221.453181095372, 181.838130578399, 
    216.538949125262, 212.407913302794, 212.82087062114, 
    197.914417285938, 221.26754031219, 184.472694969736, 
    204.124747824096, 194.51746976059, 209.452072845306, 
    197.70029677602, 189.389852035546, 238.026551504564, 
    213.272616759493, 209.350743405636, 192.209439970673, 
    226.128907106621, 185.23781793192, 204.761643599548, 
    214.069989413456, 208.494819342333, 200.178394743342, 
    223.090127686495, 228.673297329609), unit = "", names = c("layer.1", 
    "layer.2", "layer.3", "layer.4", "layer.5", "layer.6", 
    "layer.7", "layer.8", "layer.9", "layer.10", "layer.11", 
    "layer.12", "layer.13", "layer.14", "layer.15", "layer.16", 
    "layer.17", "layer.18", "layer.19", "layer.20", "layer.21", 
    "layer.22", "layer.23", "layer.24", "layer.25", "layer.26", 
    "layer.27", "layer.28", "layer.29", "layer.30", "layer.31", 
    "layer.32", "layer.33", "layer.34", "layer.35", "layer.36", 
    "layer.37", "layer.38", "layer.39", "layer.40", "layer.41", 
    "layer.42", "layer.43", "layer.44", "layer.45", "layer.46", 
    "layer.47", "layer.48", "layer.49", "layer.50", "layer.51", 
    "layer.52", "layer.53", "layer.54", "layer.55", "layer.56", 
    "layer.57", "layer.58", "layer.59", "layer.60", "layer.61", 
    "layer.62", "layer.63", "layer.64", "layer.65", "layer.66", 
    "layer.67", "layer.68", "layer.69", "layer.70", "layer.71", 
    "layer.72", "layer.73", "layer.74", "layer.75", "layer.76", 
    "layer.77", "layer.78", "layer.79", "layer.80", "layer.81", 
    "layer.82", "layer.83", "layer.84", "layer.85", "layer.86", 
    "layer.87", "layer.88", "layer.89", "layer.90", "layer.91", 
    "layer.92", "layer.93", "layer.94", "layer.95", "layer.96", 
    "layer.97", "layer.98", "layer.99", "layer.100", "layer.101", 
    "layer.102", "layer.103", "layer.104", "layer.105", "layer.106", 
    "layer.107", "layer.108", "layer.109", "layer.110", "layer.111", 
    "layer.112", "layer.113", "layer.114", "layer.115", "layer.116", 
    "layer.117", "layer.118", "layer.119", "layer.120", "layer.121", 
    "layer.122", "layer.123", "layer.124", "layer.125", "layer.126", 
    "layer.127", "layer.128", "layer.129", "layer.130", "layer.131", 
    "layer.132", "layer.133", "layer.134", "layer.135", "layer.136", 
    "layer.137", "layer.138")), legend = new(".RasterLegend", 
    type = character(0), values = logical(0), color = logical(0), 
    names = logical(0), colortable = logical(0)), title = character(0), 
extent = new("Extent", xmin = -181.40625, xmax = 178.59375, 
    ymin = -89.258464857103, ymax = 89.258464857103), rotated = FALSE, 
rotation = new(".Rotation", geotrans = numeric(0), transfun = function () 
NULL), ncols = 128L, nrows = 64L, crs = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"), 
history = list(), z = list())
```

Thank you, and any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you see any `"y"` in your `landCO2`? It's very likely that you still need `rasterToPoints` where there is a `"y"`.

Comment: Can you create a weights raster with the same resolution and extent as your landCO2 stack and use raster math to multiply the weights by the RasterStack?  Alternatively, have you considered reprojecting your RasterStack a projection that better matches your needs, maybe an equal area projection?  I don't work with worldwide data, so don't have suggestions off hand.  The second part of your question may be better suited for the GIS stack exchange site: https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jay.sf Unless because this is a Raster Stack, there is a y component (i.e. the stacking of raster layers creates a y component)? Otherwise, it is essentially composed of 8192 values per raster layer, so ideally, I would like each of these values to have the weights applied to them.

Comment: @BrianFisher I am not sure if it is possible to create another raster based off of the original landCO2 raster stack object. Maybe it is possible to re-project landCO2 to a suitable projection that takes into account the differences in area between the area and the poles by making them equal. Do you happen to know of a suitable projection to do this? Thanks

Comment: Can you make a simple self-contained reproducible example? That is create a small RasterStack/Brick in memory and show what output you want (without weighting). Then it should be easy to answer your question.

Comment: @Robert Hijmans - Thanks for your response. I added data from landCO2 (see edit in above post). I hope that this helps! Thanks, again.

Comment: Using `dput`  is a not a good way to provide example data. Rather do something like
`b <- brick(ncol=128, nrow=64, nl=2, xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84");` 
`values(b) <- c(1:ncell(b), ncell(b):1)`

Comment: @Robert Hijmans - Thank for that suggestion. I was able to have my question answered, but I will definitely keep that reproducible example in mind for future reference! Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this approach should work.

```
library(raster)
r <- landCO2[[1]] # Extracts one layer of the raster brick to pull info from. Might not be necessary

## Create raster layer that has the latitude values for each cell. using method from <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848836/r-assigning-x-or-y-coordinate-to-cells-of-a-raster-to-perform-calculations>
lats <- raster(matrix(yFromCell(r, 1:length(r)), nrow = 64, byrow = TRUE),  #get latitude from existing raster
               xmn = -181.4062, xmx=  178.5938, ymn = -89.25846, ymx = 89.25846 ,  # Set the extents of the raster
               crs = crs(r))  # Using projection of existing raster
weights <- cos(lats*(pi/180))  #Feed this raster into your weighting formula.
plot(weights) # to see what we're looking at
```

[image]

This looks reasonable with weights around 1 near the equator and falling off sharply as you approach the poles.
You can now use raster algebra to apply the weights to your RasterBrick.\

```
CO2weighted <- landCO2 * weights # this should be a RasterBrick with 138 layers.
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much! Yes, this was PRECISELY what I wanted to do, and I learned a great deal from your (clever) procedure!

Comment: You can do `lats <- init(r, "y")` but you do not need it, as you can do `weights <- area(r)`